# SQL Server mirror at night, available by day

Tags: sql-server, database, database-mirroring

I have a large (~200GB) database on server SQL-PROD. This is a production database with highly restricted access.

I want to have a copy of the database for developers to use for testing on server SQL-TEST.

My initial thought was to perform a nightly database copy, dropping and recreating the destination database on SQL-TEST but leaving the database on SQL-PROD available. This, however is proving to be incredibly slow.

Is it possible to create a mirror of the database on SQL-TEST and have mirroring run only during the night, say 00:00 to 04:00 and from 04:00 to 00:00 disable mirroring and allow read access to the database? From what I've read, if I bring the mirrored database online, the database on SQL-PROD becomes the mirror?

It seems as though, if that approach is viable, it should be faster than either a nightly database copy and faster than a backup/restore?

Comment: That's not mirroring, that's replication. SQL Server offers multiple types of replication since 2000 at least. The BOL guide is well written and explains the process. In any case, this is out-of-scope for SO. You should ask at dba.stackexchange.com *AFTER* reading about replication.

Comment: Besides, why copy the entire backup and drop the target, instead of taking a differential backup? Why recreate anything?

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up on replication.